# gnome app indicator /org/ayatana/NotificationItem/

Tags: gnome, 18.04, indicator

where is /org/ayatana/NotificationItem/ located. I thought it would be in dconf but I couldn't find it.

Comment: GNOME does not use ayatana indicators. Where did you get this `/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/` path from?

Comment: I am using an extension called icon hider[https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/] to hide icons and it was filling up with icon paths that start with that and causing issue. Turns out, It was because appindicator icons, the default extension on Ubuntu 18 for creating icons, created temporary paths for these icons that get refreshed every time gnome-shell is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 default,

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i ayatana
```

comes up empty.

`gsettings list-recursively` lists all the "schemas" along with keys and values. So it's understandable that `dconf` won't reveal any entries related to `ayatana` either.